# Missing secret gists in GitHub's API

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, github-api, gist

According to [the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/gists#list-gists-for-the-authenticated-user), I can either send the request with authorization (token) in order to get all of my gists, or anonymously and I will get public popular gists.

My Python code is:

```py
url = "https://api.github.com/gists"
with Get(
    url,
    headers={"Accept": accept},
    params={"since": since, "per_page": per_page, "page": page},
    auth=("token", token)
) as response:
    return response
```

When `token` is set to `None`, I get all public gists (***not mine***) and when `token` is set to my OAuth token, I get all of ***my*** gists.

**However, the issue is** that it only gives me my non-secret gists instead of secret and public together.

Initially I was thinking that my token was wrong and therefore I was not getting the secret gists, but turns out that the token is correct (for sure, I can even post new gists) and also has permissions to read/write gists, and that is why it is weird.

The issue is also not related to either `params` or `headers`, tested.

***Additional Information***:
***`Get`*** is a class which implements a context-manager and sends a `get` request [[link](https://github.com/jonatan1609/GithubAPI/blob/master/github/utils.py)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research I found out that GitHub's OAuth token from Developer Settings is not enough to perform this action and I need to create a GitHub App in order to extend GitHub.

I used this tool:
https://github.com/defunkt/gist
in order to ask GitHub for such a particular token (which is being used in the GitHub App), and then I started using it, and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

With the new fine grained personal access tokens this can now be done without a GitHub App:

You need to give read-write access to Gists under Account Permissions: [image: Account Permissions under Personal Access Token creation scren]